# Calculate combinations and use those as argument in cut

Tags: r, combinations

I hope someone is able to help me with this problem. Currently, I'm trying all possible combinations in binning a dataset by using multiple if-statements. For example, I will try to bin data from -Inf to i, i to j, j to Inf. I then have the following code:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  for (j in 1:10) {
    if(i/10 == j/10) next
    data$variable1_optim <- cut(data$variable1,breaks = c(-Inf, i/10, j/10, Inf))
    best_result[i,j] <- bin_power2(data$variable1_optim)
    if (min(tabulate(data$variable1_optim)) / NROW(data$variable1_optim) <= 0.05)
      best_result[i,j] <- NA
    if (length(unique(data$variable1_optim)) < 3)
      best_result[i,j] <- NA
  }
}
```

The issue with this code at the moment is that the combination [i = 0.1 , j = 0.2] produces the same results as [i=0.2 , j=0.1].  Hence, I would like to somehow generate all possible combinations, and input those in my loop instead. Unfortunately I have no clue how I can accomplish this, and Googling for my answer did not work out either.

Comment: Please provide a small example data set to work with, and show what you want as desired output. Please use `dput(...)`

Comment: Have you considered using  `for(i in 1:9)` and `for(j in (i+1):10)`?

Comment: @CPak I've solved it already, thanks :).

Comment: @Freguglia that would still give too many combinations, but using t(combn(c())) does the trick :) thanks for helping though~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAY! I finally found it after more digging through old  forum posts! For anyone wondering, this is how I solved it:

```
combin <- t(combn(c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0), 2))
best_result <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(combin)) {
  data$variable1_optim <- cut(data$variable1,breaks = c(-Inf, combin[i,1], combin[i,2], Inf))
  best_result[i] <- bin_power2(data$variable1_optim)
  if (min(tabulate(data$variable1_optim)) / NROW(data$variable1_optim) <= 0.05)
    best_result[i] <- NA
  if (length(unique(data$variable1_optim)) < 3)
    best_result[i] <- NA

}
```